# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 while displaying UIAlertView and home button pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have searched the forums regarding this and found no information on this error. I created a simple single view application in xcode and added code to create a test alert in viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Test"
                                        message:@"Alert Test"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I have not added any other code. When I run this on my iphone 4 it runs without any problem. But when I click the home button of my iphone 4 with the alert displayed I get the mentioned error.

Device: iphone 4
OS: iOS 5.1.1

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you should not display the `alertView` in [viewDidLoad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad), `[UIAlertView show]` displays the alertView using animation. we should avoid animation performance when we are not in screen/view , display the `alertView` in `viewDidAppear` instead.

EDIT:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismiss) name:@"UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}

//do not forget to add this in your header
-(void)dismiss{
   [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
 }
```

Comment: I have tried adding the alert in viewDidAppear. Same error again. I don't have any animation in my project. The alert view is the only code in my project

Comment: The error occurs when the alert view is displayed and the home button is clicked

Comment: can you let me know how can i display it without animation

Comment: I dont think thats possible. if the error occurs when you hit the home button, why not dismiss the alertView when the app enters background? , before the app become inactive, it posts `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification, you can react to that event, dismiss the alertView using `[alertView dissmissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];`

Comment: I added the alert dismiss method to both applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground. The alert gets removed but the error occurs. Also as other threads suggested, I tried calling the method using a timer and selector, but still the error is thrown when I click the home button. I found this thread which has the same problem as mine http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/97851-wait_fences-problem-with-uialertview.html

Comment: so you also want to keep the alert displayed when the user returns to you app after hitting home button?

Comment: I dont need the alert to be displayed when the user returns. Even when I close the alert in applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground, the error occurs